# assign function to multiple variables without reference

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to assign function to multiple variables, the function calls another function `getFuncName()`, I want `getFuncName` to return the name of the function that got invoked.

```
function getFuncName() {
    return getFuncName.caller.name;
}

const error = warning = info = verbose = debug = silly = message => {
        console.log(getFuncName())
}
```

When error gets invoked it prints `silly`, same for warning, info, verbose and debug.
I want that if error gets invoked, it will print `error`, same for every other variable, Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that the `const` declaration in your sample code declares **one** constant, `error`.  The other names ("warning", "info", "verbose", etc) are *not* declared as constants. Instead they are interpreted as simple references to variables declared elsewhere.,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A one-liner solution from @Patrick Roberts's answer:

```
const [error, warning, info, verbose, debug, silly] = ['error', 'warning', 'info', 'verbose', 'debug', 'silly'].map(type => msg => {console.log(type, msg);});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way you do it is to:

```
const error = message => {
  console.log(getFuncName())
}

const warning = error
const info = error
// etc
```

On the other hand why would you want to do this? Maybe you wanted to push a log level or something? In this case you could do like this (higher-order functions):

```
const logger = level => message => {
  console.log(level, ': ', getFuncName())
}

const error = logger('error')
// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use [`Function.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller), it's non-standard and does not behave consistently across browsers. It also does not work in strict mode:

```js
'use strict';

function foo () {
  function bar () {
    console.log(bar.caller.name);
  }
  
  return bar();
}

foo();
```

Just use partial application to create a closure for `message => { ... }`:

```js
'use strict';

const logger = type => message => {
  console.log(type, message);
};

const error = logger('error');
const warning = logger('warning');
const info = logger('info');
const verbose = logger('verbose');
const debug = logger('debug');
const silly = logger('silly');

error('foo');
info('bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, besides `getFuncName`, there is only a *single* function in existence. It's referred to via 6 different variables, but there is *only one function, with one name*.

You can't expect the same function to have different names at different times. Anonymous functions can be given a default name by the interpreter when they appear in the code assigned to a variable - in the case that the anonymous function is assigned to multiple variables at once, the rightmost variable name ("silly", in your case) is considered the name of the function.